# Include js файл в js файл

Tags: include, javascript

Как осуществляется данный include?

Comment: Есть вариант на jQuery (*точнее: jQuery + Ajax*) - [$.getScript()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_js_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1):

Языком такая возможность не поддерживается. Почитай вот [тут](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/technogrette/js/include/), вроде бы неплохая статья.

Comment: плохой способ. у Лебедева вообще только орфограф, декодер да промышленный дизайн нормально работают и выглядят.